# Strange error when trying to import ASGI into settings.py

Tags: python, django, websocket, daphne

I'm doing a project: simple web-chat and I need the help of websockets for continuous connection and data proccesing. Everything would be fine, but an error crashes that it is not possible to import ASGI. How can i fix it?

here my setting.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'daphne',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'chat',
    'django_filters',
    'rest_framework',
    'channels',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'chatajax.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'chatajax.wsgi.application'


MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 6379)],
        },
    },
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

SITE_ID = 1


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "****"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "****"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static"
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = "chatajax.asgi.application"


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

asgi.py:

```
import os
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator


from chat.routing import websocket_urlpatterns
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

import chat.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": django_asgi_app,
        "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
            AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns))
        ),
    }
)
```

routing:

```
from django.urls import re_path
from .consumers import ChatConsumer
from channels.routing import URLRouter


websocket = URLRouter([
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_title>\w+)/$', ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
])
```

and consumers file:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json


class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_title = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_title']
        self.room_group_title = f'chat_{self.room_title}'

        await self.send({'type': 'websocket.accept'})

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_title,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_title,
            self.channel_name
        ) 

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_title,
            {
                'type': 'chat.message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }
        ))
```

I tried to search the internet for a solution to this problem, because after multiple attempt to change something myself(well, for example, I completely rewrote the routing, consumers and asgi.py files), but there was nothing there that could help me

That's an error:

```
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module %r" % path)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module 'chatajax.asgi'
```